# Does the match query return only results base on score?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

Hello I have the following object:

```
{
  type:'foo'
  users: [{id: MyId roles:['Admin','FooAdmin']}, 
            {id: MyId2 roles:['Admin']}]
}
```

And I was using a bool query to get this objects by the users id. with the following term:

```
'term': {
         'users.id': 'myId'
        }
```

It works well except when the id Has capital letters in it. I searched a little and found out the match query as an alternative:

```
{
 "query":
   {
    "match":
     {
      "users.userId":token._source.userId
     }
   }
}
```

So far its been working well for me because it is case sensitive. But lately i've heard that the match query only gets the 'best results',meaning that only gets results with the best score. Is this true? I'm I risking to not get all the objects i want with the match query?

Comment: A you looking to get objects that have _exactly_ the id `MyId` i.e. similar to a SQL WHERE clause of `WHERE MyId2 = 'myId'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match query takes the query string, [analyzes it](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/09/18/the-simple-power-of-elasticsearch-analyzers/), and then turns the analyzed tokens into an OR query. The reason is its case sensitive is because there's a [lowercase filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) in the analyzer.

So a query string like

`"brown dog"`

would get turned into two tokens and lowercased, something like

`[brown] OR [dog]`

Which will both retrieve and rank results based on relevance for those two terms. The relevance formula is itself complex, but you'll get all the results just SORTED on relevance.

The exception is the argument minimum_should_match, if you set this you can control how many terms in the OR query above must match for the document to be in the resulting set. However, this defaults to 1, so it won't impact you here.

If you want exact string matching but with lowercasing without this tokenization business, you can create a custom analyzer that strings together a KeywordTokenizer (basically means no tokenizer) and a lowercase filter.

Comment: What I want is something like you described but without the lowercase.In other words I want a query that is case sensitive and gives me the matches for the exact string i put in the query. can that be done with the match query? can the OR query be turned into an AND query?

Comment: then you simply want to change the query to not_analyzed to disable all analysis completely